# Issue about Spring MVC with bootstrap

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

First of all this is my first question and I really need your help. I wanted to improve my J2EE skills and to do that, I started to do some tutorials. But I have a problem in dispatcher servlet.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mywebsiteq</groupId>
<artifactId>emusicstoreq</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

here is the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstoreq" />

   <mvc:annotation-driven />

   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

          <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
          <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
```

Here is capture of the exact error that I keep getting:

[image]

the screenshot of the folder structure:

[image]

I am getting this error and I have no idea how can I solve this. I have tried to check the internet but I could not find a way to solve it.

If anyone can help me, I really would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`location` attribute must point to public web resource. look at following java doc description

> The resource location from which to serve static content, specified at a Spring Resource pattern. Each location 
>    must point to a valid directory. Multiple locations may be specified as a comma-separated list, and the locations 
>    will be checked for a given resource in the order specified. For example, a value of "/, classpath:/META-INF/
>    public-web-resources/" will allow resources to be served both from the web app root and from any JAR on the 
>    classpath that contains a /META-INF/public-web-resources/ directory, with resources in the web app root taking 
>    precedence.

static content must lie outside WEB-INF directory. If you keep your resource folder in parent of WEB-INF i.e. Application root then your tag will be as follows :

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

Comment: Nope, it does not work still. I am getting the same error. "Cannot resolve location and Spring XML model validation".

Comment: where is your resources folder ? provide the path

Comment: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/resources. this is the path where the sources folder is.

Comment: thats what move resources folder to webapp directory. the path must be  src/main/webapp/resources. provide the screenshot of folder structure of your project.

Comment: are you using eclipse - dynamic web project ? if yes then move the resource folder to WebContent folder

Comment: I moved my folders under the path which is /webapp/resources, still same error is showing up.

Comment: screenshot of  folder structure of your project will help to resolve the issue

Comment: I am using Intellij btw

Comment: check [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/enabling-web-application-support.html?origin=old_help#d1768608e335).  I think there is web directory content folder in Intellij UI. Keep your resources folder under this web directory

Comment: I've added the screenshot of the folder structure.

Comment: do maven clean and install

Answer (score 2):

Try using this

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

if didn't worked, then check what the new error is.

Comment: Nope, it does not work still. I am getting the same error. "Cannot resolve location and Spring XML model validation"

Comment: just check where your resource folder is.
mainly the directory structure for spring mvc looks like this
resources and WEB-INF folders are inside webapp folder.
check, whether you have that structure? @MartinC.

Comment: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/resources. this is the path where the sources folder is. as you said, the folder is in the correct place. under the WEB-INF and WEB-INF is under the webapp folder.